# Updating URL with parameters from checkbox (without a hash)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am using the following code snippet to pass parameters to URL so the specific search can be accessed via the generated link.

For example, if `Potato` is selected, then the URL changes to `example.com#potato`

However, instead of appending the URL with a hash, I want to append `?filter=`

So if `Potato` is selected, I want the URL to change to `example.com?filter=potato`

How can I achieve this?

```js
$(function() {
  $(".vegetables, .seasoning").on("change", function() {
    var hash = $(".vegetables:checked, .seasoning:checked").map(function() {
      return this.value;
    }).toArray();
    hash = hash.join(",");
    location.hash = hash;
  });

  if (location.hash !== "") {
    var hash = location.hash.substr(1).split(",");
    hash.forEach(function(value) {
      $("input[value=" + value + "]").prop("checked", true);
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>Filter recipes:</h3>

<div>
  <p>Select vegetables</p>
  <label><input type="checkbox" class="vegetables" value="potato"> Potato</label><br>
  <label><input type="checkbox" class="vegetables" value="onion"> Onion</label><br>
  <label><input type="checkbox" class="vegetables" value="tomato"> Tomato</label><br>
</div>

<div>
  <p>Select seasoning</p>
  <label><input type="checkbox" class="seasoning" value="salt"> Salt</label><br>
  <label><input type="checkbox" class="seasoning" value="pepper"> Pepper</label><br>
  <label><input type="checkbox" class="seasoning" value="chilli"> Chilli Flakes</label><br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pushState()` to update the current URL without reloading the page:

```js
$(".vegetables, .seasoning").on("change", function() {
  var values = $(".vegetables:checked, .seasoning:checked").map((i, el) => el.value).get();
  window.history.pushState({}, '', `?filter=${values.join(',')}`);
});
```

Comment: Thanks Rory! This does a great job at changing it to ?filter= instead of hash, which is great, but in using this snippet alone I lose the functionality of being able to refresh the page with the filtered URL and get those choices automatically selected by default (like my original code snippet does). How can I for those specific inputs to be checked on page load if they exist in the ?filter= parameter ?